# 'Data Access Layer' é a mesma coisa que 'Data Access Object'?

Tags: c#, .net

Eu sempre usei o DAO (Data Access Object) em Java Web e agora que estou partindo para a plataforma .NET (C#), vi que existe a camada DAL (Data Access Layer). Fiquei confuso, o DAL seria a mesma coisa do DAO? Pois eu vi uns exemplo que usavam uma camada DAL e dentro dela criava-se o *model* e etc.

Comment: Data Access Layer ?

Comment: sim, essa mesmo...

Comment: War Lock, fiz algumas alterações para melhorar o título e tornar a pergunta mais objetiva, você pode [reverter](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/48868/revisions) caso ache necessário.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

São coisas diferentes.

DAL (***Data Access Layer***) - É um projeto/camada responsável pela estrutura para acesso e persistência dos dados da aplicação. É um padrão de arquitetura para separação da estrutura de acesso a base de dados da camada de apresentação da aplicação.

O DAL possui objetos DAO (***Data Access Object***) que escondem a complexidade da lógica de acesso a dados. DAO é um padrão de projeto.

Exemplo:

Imagine um cenário de acesso a base de dados, onde você tem códigos com a configuração/criação de sua conexão como esse (abaixo) espalhados na sua camada de apresentação de dados:

```
...

var conexao = New OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DATASource=c:\Teste.mdb" );
conexao.Open();
comando = New OleDbCommand( "Insert INTO Teste ( Nome ) Values ( 'Xpto' )", conexao );
comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
conexao.Close();

...
```

Isso te levaria a replicação de código, dificuldade de manter o código espalhado pela aplicação e qualquer alteração no acesso aos dados implica na alteração de toda a aplicação.

A idéia do DAO é que essa responsabilidade deve ser concentrada em uma camada separada e independente de demais camadas.

A camada de apresentação não deve conter nenhuma referência a esse código de acesso a dados.

Cria-se uma interface para que as demais camadas utilizem os métodos de acesso a dados.

Exemplo:

```
public interface IClienteDAO<T>
{
   List<T> ExibirTodos(  );
   void Gravar(T obj);                                                        
   List<Cliente> Consultar(string nome);
}
```

Implementação de IClienteDAO:

```
public class ClienteDAO : IClienteDAO<Cliente>
{    
   public List<Cliente> Consultar(string nome)
   {
       try 
       {
          using (SqlConnection con = ConexaoBD.GetInstancia.GetConnection()) {
          try 
          {
             con.Open();
             string sql = ("Select nome, idade from clientes where nome = '" + nome + "'");
             ...
          } 
          catch (SqlException ex) 
          {
              throw ex;
          } 
        ...
       }
    }

    //Demais métodos como ExibirTodos, Gravar...
}
```

Referências: [DAO](http://www.macoratti.net/11/10/pp_dao1.htm), [DAL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581778.aspx)

Comment: continuei sem entender o dal, como fica a estrutura das camadas usando Dal e Dao? da um exemplo

Comment: @WarLock a "grosso modo" seria isso: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Qf4bO.png

Answer (score 0):

Bom, pelo que sei as definições estão corretas:

DAL (Data Access Layer) e
DAO (Data Access Object)

Acredito que a diferença seja que DAL seja uma definição para a camada de acesso a banco de dados e DAO seja o objeto que realiza essa transação.

Por exemplo, no visual studio, nós podemos criar class librarys, acho que no java são equivalentes a packages, imagine que teremos uma class library que será nossa DAL (camada de acesso a base de dados). Então nós temos um objeto Cliente que tem alguns
atributos. O DAO (uma classe por exemplo Cliente_Dao), será o responsável pelos métodos de persistencia desses atributos na base de dados.

Espero ter contribuido.